# Angular material not working on Angular13

Tags: angular, angular-material

I installed Angular Material on my project and that was not loading.

I tried importing Style sheets to the global Style.css

restarted server

But the Angular Material was not updating.

I don't get any clue.

Here below I added my Package.Json file too

***My HTml Code***

```
<mat-form-field>
  <textarea MatInput rows="6" [(ngModel)]="valueEntered"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>

<hr />
<button (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
<p>{{ newPost }}</p>
```

***app Module code***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { postCreateComponent } from './posts/post-create/post-create.component';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; 
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    postCreateComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  exports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***Package Json File***

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

Comment: How do you know it is not? Have you checked the versions in package.json? Do you any error message on installation, or on running, etc

Comment: No I didn't get any error while installation. Once after the I wrote this code. Started ng serve. I am not able to see the material design over there in browser

Comment: I am using Angular 13.0

Comment: Didn't get any error while running also

Answer (score 1):

Should do `ng add @angular/material` and add to imports and exports of `NgModule` `MatFormFieldModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule`.

Comment: Added import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
Still the same

Comment: Just to be sure, also do `npm install` again.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the problem of material UI component is loaded without style.
and in console if you are getting below message
**Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming**

just add below line in style.css and restart the application

```
   @import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

there are other css file are present in same path /node-modules like indigo
then to change color just add it in style.css or respective component's CSS file
for ex style.css    `.mat-toolbar { background: #007bff; color: #fff; }`

sample-component.html`<mat-toolbar style="background:primary" > <span>My Application</span> </mat-toolbar>`

Answer (score 0):

Just one thing I noticed in case anyone else misses it:  "MatInput" on your HTML needs to be camel case "matInput".

Answer (score 0):

My answer might sound stupid, but it was the problem I had --

I used a separate `MaterialModule`. In the beginning, I **imported** a module, but I did **NOT export** it. That's why Angular material was **NOT** working:

[image]

I searched, but I couldn't find the solution to my problem.

Then I found it out myself. So I also added the same module to the **export** array:

[image]

And then Angular material **started to work**.

Yeah, sometimes it's just some rookie mistakes.